Playwright Tests Fail in CI with net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED but Pass Locally
I am running Playwright tests on a local server (http://localhost:3000). The tests pass without issues on my local machine, but in the CI pipeline, the tests fail with the following error:
Error: page.goto: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:3000/

Local Machine:

OS: macOS
Node.js Version: 16
Playwright Version: 1.39.0

CI Environment:

Platform: GitHub Actions
Node.js Version: 16
Playwright Version: 1.39.0

Here is my playwright.config.js:
const { devices } = require('@playwright/test');



const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/en/';


const config = {
  testDir: './tests',

  timeout: 30 * 1000,
  expect: {

    timeout: 5000
  },

  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    actionTimeout: 0,
    // baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/en/',
    baseURL: baseURL,

    trace: 'on',

    locale: 'en-US'

  },

  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome']
      }
    },

    {
      name: 'Chrome Half Size',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: { width: 800, height: 600 }, // Half size viewport
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'Mobile Chrome',
      use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'Mobile Safari',
      use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    },

  ],

  outputDir: 'test-results/',

  webServer: {
    command: 'yarn dev',
    timeout: 120 * 1000,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    url: baseURL
    // port: 3000,
  }
};

module.exports = config;

Here is my workflow file:
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master, actions]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master, actions]
jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: cityflagv2
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    env:
      DB_MONGO_URL: ${{ secrets.DB_MONGO_URL }}
      SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD }}
      SENTRY_URL: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_URL }}
      SENTRY_ORG: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_ORG }}
      SENTRY_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_PROJECT }}
      SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN }}
      BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.BASE_URL }}
      MYSQL_HOST: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_HOST }}
      MYSQL_DB: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DB }}
      MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}
      MYSQL_PASS: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASS }}
      MYSQL_CONNECTION_LIMIT: 10
      
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Verify DB exists
        run: mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306 -uroot -proot -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'cityflagv2'"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/ && npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "${{ secrets.FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}" && yarn install
      - name: Lint
        run: yarn lint
      - name: Install Playwright Browsers
        run: yarn playwright install --with-deps
      - name: Run Playwright tests
        run: npx playwright test tests/index.spec.js
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
        with:
          name: playwright-report
          path: playwright-report/
          retention-days: 30

  deploy:
    needs: test
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: cd /home/ubuntu/irysteams && git pull
      - run: cd /home/ubuntu/irysteams && yarn install
      - run: cd /home/ubuntu/irysteams && yarn prestart
      - run: pm2 reload name

Troubleshooting steps taken:

Verified that the server starts correctly.
Added a wait time to ensure the server is ready before running tests.
Checked for port conflicts and ensured no other processes are using port 3000.
Compared the environment configuration between local and CI.

Observations:

The URL bar is empty in the network trace for the failing tests.
The baseURL is set correctly in the configuration.

What could be causing the net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in the CI pipeline but not locally? The tests passes for the chromium browsers but fails on the other 2 on page.goto("/").
